# iPhone - how to find what object is it referring?

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging

What's the point of Xcode showing the object address in messages like

**[CALayer retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1bc320**

if when it happens you cannot find which object 0x1bc320 is?

Every time I see stuff like that I search the debugger for all objects that I can find and I never find which object is the one it is referring on the error message.

wasn't it logical just to say
**[CALayer retain]: message sent to deallocated instance.**

Is that any way to find the object when that happens? Something I can type on console or something?

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just type `po 0x1bc320`. You can also use allocations tracking in Instruments with `NSZombie` tracking enabled. That will halt the app and show you the full lifecycle of the zombied object and who called it after deallocation.

Comment: I have NSZombie always enabled in this cases but this never helps. I have tried typing what you said, and this is the message: ** -[CALayer respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1bc320

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x35823910 in ___forwarding___ ()
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB has restored the context to what it was before the call.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal off"
Evaluation of the expression containing the function (_NSPrintForDebugger) will be abandoned.

Comment: continued... what do you mean "this will show the full lifecycle of the zombie object and who called it after deallocation... " where exactly will it show that?

Comment: I highly recommend you read up on how to use Instruments. It's a bit complex to explain here, but if you add the Object Allocation instrument to your run, open its settings and enable "NSZombie Detection" you'll see what I mean (assuming you know how to use Instruments to traverse an object's lifecycle and all that).

Comment: Where would one type po 0x1bc320?

Comment: The gdb (debugger) console in Xcode or the command line (depending on where you're running it from).

Comment: $0 = 174104656 [no Objective-C description available] is the output for my error "2014-04-22 20:56:56.137 SalesApp[3174:19d03] *** -[UIViewAnimationContext respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xa60a050"--What does it mean?